# Attempting to run a basic app on Heroku local

Tags: heroku, mern

I am new to app development so I'm sure this is an easy question for you seasoned pros out there.

I have a simple MERN stack app running in development using concurrently to run both the front-end and back-end.  Before I deploy my app to Heroku I wanted to validate that it will run with the Heroku command line "Heroku local web".  This successfully starts my server and connects my database but it does not start the front end at all.  I think this may be something wrong with my package.json scripts but I have tried everything.  My scripts are as follows:

```
"scripts": {
    "install-client": "cd client && npm install",
    "start": "node server.js",
    "build": "cd client && npm run build",
    "client": "cd client && npm start",
    "dev": "concurrently -n 'server,client' -c 'red,green' \"nodemon server.js\" \"npm run client\"",
    "heroku-postbuild": "npm run install-client && npm run build",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you run your app on your local machine with `npm run dev` but according to heroku's documentation [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#default-web-process-type) they start your app with `npm start` unless specified otherwise by a file named `Procfile` in your app’s root directory.

The start script in your package.json file indeed runs only the server (`node server.js`).

Try copying the content of the `dev` script to the `start` script, or adding a file named `Procfile` with the single line:

```
web: npm run dev
```

or whatever command you use, in your app’s root directory.